# Why does my express error handler not work with "fetch" or "xhr" requests?

Tags: express, error-handling, fetch, custom-error-handling

I have an error-catching wrapper function

and a error-handling wrapper function for my route handlers:

```
function catchAsync(func) {
return function (res, req, next) {
func(req, res, next).catch((err) => {
next(err)
})
}}
```

which wraps around my express route-handling-functions (`async(req,res)=>{...logic...}`)like so:

```
app.put('/note/:noteId', catchAsync(async(req,res)=>{
...logic...
}))
```

And a custom error handler at the end of my app.js:

```
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
const { status = 500 } = err
res.status(status).render('error', { error: err, status })
})
```

..which renders the error.ejs with the error message and status

When I intentionally trigger an error through leaving a required form field blank (after DOMPurify.sanitize-ing it), express catches it fine when I submit a form through the express-handling regular/default way,but when I use a custom submitter (so the page won't reload automatically) with "fetch" (which works fine for regular use),

custom form-submitter-function:

```
const saveEdit = (address,...etc) => {
    fetch(`${address}`, {
        method: 'PUT',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
        body: `${...}`,
    })
        .then(resp => resp.json())//this part throws a second error cuz it get's nothing back
        .then(...)
        .catch((err)=>{console.log('error in fetch', err)})
    }
```

the expresses error handler doesn't handle the error passed off from catchAsync and render the error.ejs page. Instead my fetch request gets nothing back and and so the resp.json() throws its own error (unexpected token...blahblah) which i get after the "Internal Server Error" (which express was supposed throw an error page for).

Can anyone explain why this happens and if there's a way that I can make it so the custom express error handler will throws up the page, even if the request is made with "fetch/xhr"? Thanks!

I've tried a bunch of things including modifying catchAsync so it manually renders the error page, but I guess "res.render" doesn't work unless it's after an app.verb()
------ Here's the full code of the functions, if it's of any help:

```
const saveEdit = (edittedNoteForm, edittedNote, extras, address, edittedContent) => {
    //format data to urlencoded
    const editNoteFD = new FormData(edittedNoteForm)
    const editNoteUrlEnc = formDataToURLEncoded(editNoteFD, edittedContent)

    //send to route and have route send back note object
    fetch(`${address}`,{// in this case, address="/note/:noteId"
        method: 'PUT',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
        body: `${editNoteUrlEnc}&extras=${extras}`,
    })
        .then(resp => resp.json())
        .then(responseNote => {
            //get html of a updated note for display
            edittedNote.innerHTML = formatNoteHTML(responseNote)
            //add event listeners to "edit" and "save" buttons/forms
            addSubmitListenerToChildElement(edittedNote, 'edit_note', getEditForm) //1st param parent elment, second child's ID, third, callback
            addSubmitListenerToChildElement(edittedNote, 'delete_note', deleteNote)
        })
        .catch((err)=>{console.log('error in fetch', err)})
    }
```

```
app.put('/note/:noteId', catchAsync(async(req,res)=>{
    const edittedNoteReqBody = parseAndCleanReqBody(req.body)
    let note = await Note.findById(req.params.noteId)
    if (edittedNoteReqBody.extras === 'false'){ // only the note.text field has been changed
        note.note.text = edittedNoteReqBody.note.text
    } else { // rewrite all form inputs
        const {note: noteNested, section, video} = edittedNoteReqBody
        note.note = noteNested
        note.section = section;
        note.video = video;
    }
    await note.save()
    res.send(note)
}))
```

Comment: What's the relation between `func` in the `catchAsync` wrapper and `saveEdit`?

Comment: Not much. It just sends the request to the route. Sorry I forgot to put the route-handler and its function: `app.put('/note/:noteId', catchAsync(async(req,res)=>{ ...logic... }))` in "codeblock" when writing the comment. I think it's clearer now.

Comment: Assuming that your "...logic..." calls `saveEdit()`, you are not returning a promise from it and probably don't `await` it either, so the `func()` promise never is rejected with the error where it could be caught

Comment: Thanks for the input. "saveEdit" is the one that calls the route-handlers code (which is wrapped in "catchAsync"). I included the full code of the abbreviated functions. Since "catchAsync" will execute the route-handler's code and catch and pass off any errors thrown inside to express (with ".catch((err)=>next(err)), I think there's no need for returning a promise? After looking at the full functions, what do you think?

Comment: Oh I misunderstood the way they're calling each other, so `saveEdit` is on the frontend. Then it's ok.

Comment: "*my fetch request gets nothing back and and so the resp.json() throws "unexpected token...blahblah" which i get after the "Internal Server Error", that express was supposed throw an error page for*". So what exactly is the http response that your server sends? And what errors do you see in your server logs?

Comment: my broswer console says:
`PUT http://localhost:3000/note/64238157b70be11495fec1f3? 500 (Internal Server Error)`//me: this is caused by failed schema validation....
and then beneath that it says:
`error in fetch SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON` //me: this is the problem thrown from "saveEdit", from not getting back the proper object/JSON it expected.

I'm running it locally, so there's no server log, but the node console shows nothing. If I include `console.log(Error, err._message)` in catchAsync before `next(err)`, I get `Error Note validation failed`

Comment: Well what does `.render('error', { error: err, status })` do in your error handler? Looks like you're sending a HTML document in the response.

Comment: Try adding `'Accept': 'application/json'` to your request headers

Comment: "*I'm running it locally, so there's no server log*" - regardless whether the server runs on your pc, in the cloud, or elsewhere, there's always a server. The nodejs console is what I mean - and indeed logging from the error handler is a good idea

Comment: Yes, the .render() renders an ejs page notifying you of the error. As mentioned earlier, it all works fine when the request is through the default router, and not through fetch or xhr. I'm guessing because the fetch request needs to get its response (even if it's an error), somehow that overrides express's error handling system or something. The header didn't change anything, unfortunately.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "*when the request is through the default router*". `fetch`/xhr are clients and having nothing to do with routing.

Comment: "*`resp.json()` - this part throws a second error cuz it get's nothing back*" - actually it *does* get something back, you get the error because that thing is not JSON. You should both check the response status (e.g. `resp.ok`) as well as the content-type header of the response before attempting to parse it as JSON.

Comment: good to know. Tx. What I mean by "default router" (yeah, probably should have said default-submitter) is I let express auto/normally-handle form "submit"s rather than adding an submit-eventlistener to the form, with e.preventDefault() to manually submit the form's input info to the "action=" address/route with fetch.

Comment: I just realized my express app was handling the error properly, and sending back the ejs page, that I want to see as a response (I can see the full-page response if I remove the .catch() from fetch). I guess it can be handled by the browser, np, but not "fetch". Gotta figure out now how to manually render this now.

Comment: I would suggest to change your custom error handler. It should inspect the `accept` request, and only if that contains `html` (or is missing altogether), render the error page. If the clients accepts only a json response, use `res.status(status).json({error, status})` instead. [This follows the HTTP standard](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Content_negotiation) solution for this problem :-)